# Core dump in Docker container is larger than the disk size

Tags: docker, coredump

I have a container that is creating core dump and the file is reported as being larger than the actual filesystem.

Core dump is shown as 124 GB but filesystem is only 30 GB, and there is still 12 GB of that free.

I know I could restrict the size of the core dumps by setting the container ulimit in the `docker run` command, but my questions here are:

- Why is the core file seemingly so large?
- What is the *real* size of the dump file?

Clearly the reported file size is incorrect and I'm guessing it's related to the overlay filesystem but is it a bug or expected behaviour in some way?

I've tried Googling this, both with and without mentioning Docker, but the only remotely relevant thing I found is [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/core-dump-is-larger-than-file-space-left-on-disk-699253/).

Some relevant info:

- Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a
- Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
- AWS `t3.xlarge` instance (16 GB RAM)

```
$ docker system df -v
Images space usage:

REPOSITORY           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED ago         SIZE                SHARED SIZE         UNIQUE SiZE         CONTAINERS
my-image             latest              df2c7bc0cc50        10 months ago ago   1.608GB             917.7MB             690MB               1


Containers space usage:

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  LOCAL VOLUMES       SIZE                CREATED ago         STATUS              NAMES
f7a9de1659d0        my-image                     "gunicorn --config g…"   0                   124GB               6 months ago ago    Up 13 days          abc
```

```
$ docker ps --size
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                 NAMES     SIZE
f7a9de1659d0        my-image                     "gunicorn --config g…"   6 months ago        Up 13 days          5000/tcp, 8000/tcp    abc       124GB (virtual 126GB)
```

```
$ df -h
Filesystem       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs            1.6G   26M  1.6G   2% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1    30G   18G   12G  60% /
tmpfs            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
```

Some from inside the container:

```
root@f7a9de1659d0:/app# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          30G   18G   12G  60% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/firmware
```

```
root@f7a9de1659d0:/app# ls -l
total 1474124
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root           40 Sep 17  2018 Procfile
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root         4096 Mar  6  2019 __pycache__
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root         2487 Oct 22  2018 app.py
-rw------- 1 root root 124045455360 Sep 16 11:31 core
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root          801 Sep 17  2018 gunicorn.conf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root         1815 Sep 17  2018 readme.md
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root           64 Sep 17  2018 requirements.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root          412 Sep 17  2018 client.py
```

```
root@f7a9de1659d0:/app# file core 
core: ELF 64-bit LSB core file x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), too many program headers (29701)
```

```
root@f7a9de1659d0:/app# ulimit -c
unlimited
```

Edit: Added an option to make the above `file` command work:

```
root@f7a9de1659d0:/app# file -Pelf_phnum=30000 core
core: ELF 64-bit LSB core file x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style, from '/usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn --config gunicorn.conf app:app', real uid: 0, effective uid: 0, real gid: 0, effective gid: 0, execfn: '/usr/local/bin/gunicorn', platform: 'x86_64'
```

Comment: Looks weird. If I had this problem, I would start from the following: (a) open the original core dump with GDB to ensure that it is correct and usable; (b) copy this file out of the container file system (out of overlay) and check the size of the copy; (c) if the size of the copy is still huge, archive this file to see the real amount of meaningful data inside it (pass the file through `tar` and `tar + gzip`, check the sizes of the resulting files).

Comment: And just for sure: could you add the amount of RAM and swap you use on the host? Lastly, is this issue reproducible in your environment, or you face it first time and never seen before?

Comment: This is running on an AWS t3.xlarge instance, so that's 16GB RAM. There is no swap configured (AWS instances by default have no swap, and I haven't added any).

Comment: I have modified the `file` command in the question to add more info.
I'll copy the file out of container tomorrow and run the other tests

Comment: I just tried copying the file out with `docker cp` and it ran out of disk space. i.e. it used up the 12 GB free space, then failed.